# How can I change multiple characters in a string of input? (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, replace, char

I'm trying to create a program that replaces certain characters or groups of characters with a different character or piece of text.

what I have so far is

```
def changeWords(sentence):
    for char in sentence:
        if char == 'a':
            printSameLine('x')
        elif char == 'bd':
            printSameLine('y')
        else:
            printSameLine(char)

def goWordChange():
    print('')
    print('paste text to change')
    print('')
    text = input()
    print('')
    changeWords(text)
    print('')
    return goWordChange()

goWordChange()
```

If for the input I type in "abcd acbd"

the output will be

> xbcd xcbd

but I want it to be

> xbcd xcy

I'm not quite sure why it can replace the "a" but not the "bc".  How can I get it to change more than one character?

(ps. I am still a beginner at programming so please use small words :))

Comment: Are you deliberately trying to avoid the `replace()` method that strings have as a learning exercise or just not using it because you hadn't heard of it? Example usage: `"abad".replace('a', 'c') == "cbcd"` and `"abad".replace('ab', 'x') == "xad"`. I'll write up a version not using `replace` if you're trying to avoid it and a version using it otherwise.

Comment: Oh okay thanks, to answer your question I'm not avoiding it I've just never used "replace()" before because I'm an extreme noob.  can you tell me how/where exactly the .replace() thing fits in with the rest of the program?

Comment: I've added an answer to expand on what I said in my comment. Please ask if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your code wasn't coping with replacements of substrings that were multiple characters long is because your loop `for char in sentence:` loops over *one character at a time*. To see this put a `print(char)` call just after that loop in your code and see if `char` is ever equal to `'bd'`.

Handily strings in python have a method called `replace` which returns a new string will all the occurrences of the substring old replaced with the string new. This stops you having to worry about looping over chars or pairs of chars or whatever (although it might be a good exersise to try and solve the problem without `replace` sometime). Here is an example in the python interpreter:

```
>>> string = "Hello World!"
>>> new_string = string.replace("o", "a")
>>> print(string)
Hello World!
>>> print(new_string)
Hella Warld!
>>> print(string.replace("Hello", "Goodbye"))
Goodbye World!
```

Its worth emphasising that `replace` *doesn't change the initial string* it just returns a new string with the changes made.

Here is how that might fit into your program:

```
def changeWords(sentence):
    temp_sentence = sentence.replace("a","x")
    temp_sentence = temp_sentence.replace("bd", "y")
    return temp_sentence
```

Or more compactly you can just do:

```
def changeWords(sentence):
    return sentence.replace("a","x").replace("bd", "y")
```

Then you'd need to change `goWordChange` to something like this:

```
def goWordChange():
    print('')
    print('paste text to change')
    print('')
    text = input()
    print('')
    new_text=changeWords(text)
    print('')
    print(new_text)
    return goWordChange()
```

Incidentally having `goWordChange` being recursive (calling itself at the end) like that is a bit ugly in this context. I'd get rid of that line and have `goWordChange` be called in an infinite loop like this instead:

```
while True:
    goWordChange()
```

As that form makes it a bit more obvious what is going on and it likely to have better performance (and python limits recursion depth).

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the `replace` method, which is available for `string` objects.

Consider this example:

```
>>> txt = 'Hello, world'
>>> txt = txt.replace('world', 'everyone')
>>> txt
'Hello, everyone'
```

You can do/use this for each set of char sequences you wish to replace. Note that the modified value is returned as a new string object because string are immutable (i.e. cannot be modified).

Therefore, if you simply do `txt.replace('unwanted text', 'wanted text')`, the `txt` will still hold the former value.